# Is it possible to show and interact with the Finder (Mac) via a Menu Bar App?

Tags: macos, swift, menu, osx-yosemite, finder

Is it possible to show and interact with the Finder (Mac) via a Menu Bar App? And if it is, how do I do that in Swift? I have very little coding experience, but want to develop a MenuBar App.

Comment: I guess it is possible. If I remember correctly I was able to interact with Finder using AppleScript. Therefor I believe you should be able to interact with Finder in Swift.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. If not, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Comment: @Andrej Thanks a lot I will try this^^